# Declare an array so that the address is aligned on 16 byte boundaries

Tags: c++, sdk, vivado, cortex-a

I have an uint8 array and I need to pass the pointer of this array to a DMA, which transfers 16 bytes at once. So, the requirement is that the array address is 16 byte aligned, like 32'hxxxxxx00 - the last two address numbers to be 0.
I declare a global array as follows:

```
u8 R00_PRO_ADDR[0x64000]    __attribute__ ((aligned(16)));// 16 bytes address aligned
```

however, at the runtime, I see that the address of the array is 32'hxxxxxxx0. I also tried to do (aligned(128)) but get the same result.

This is specific to Vivado SDK Cortex A53

Comment: What happens if you use `alignas(16) u8 R00_PRO_ADDR[0x64000];`?

Comment: [alignas](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Declare an array so that the address is aligned on 16 byte boundaries

You can use the standard keyword `alignas`. No need to use a language extension:

```
alignas(16) u8 R00_PRO_ADDR[0x64000];
```

> So, the requirement is that the array address is 16 byte aligned, like 32'hxxxxxx00 - the last two address numbers to be 0.

Your requirements are mixed. If you need this, then the address needs to be aligned on a 256 byte boundary:

```
alignas(256) u8 R00_PRO_ADDR[0x64000];
```

Note that a language implementation might not necessarily support arbitrarily strict alignments. If it doesn't, it should tell you so.

Comment: Ups, that was my bad. Cannot believe I miscalculated, so I was doing everything right and it worked.

Comment: The syntax that you suggested gives error "expected declaration specifiers or '...' before numeric constant". The original syntax as in my question works fine.

Comment: @Nazar You may be using an ancient version of C++ language. `alignas` was introduced in C++11. If so, keep using the language extension.

Comment: @eerorika or he is just missing some `-std=c++11`-like flag (do no know the compiler vivado supplies but it's likely gcc or clang based, and I doubt that it doesn't support c++11 at at least language level, since A53 arch is newer than C++11 support in the compilers).

Comment: @DanM. Well, if they are missing `-std=c++11` and their compiler uses an older standard by default, then they are using an ancient version of C++ language. Even if their compiler isn't as ancient.

Comment: @eerorika It's not that part I have a problem with. It's just that there are likely better options than "keep using non-standard extension", like "add a std switch".

Comment: @DanM. If OP has to use a language version that does not have the necessary standard feature, then using language extension is the only reasonable option. If OP can use a non-ancient version of the language, then there is indeed a better option: Just use `alignas`.